# MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing

Tags: mongodb, debugging

Why this error

```
MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing
```

in my mongodb nodejs code
This error shows MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing, i tried to fix but i can’t fix it.

```
findPosts: (userId) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.get().collection(COLLECTIONS.POSTS).aggregate([
                {
                    $match: { user: ObjectId(userId) }
                },
                {
                    $sort: { timestamp: -1 }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: COLLECTIONS.USERS,
                        localField: 'user',
                        foreignField: '_id',
                        as: 'author'
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: COLLECTIONS.USERS,
                        localField: 'upvote.user',
                        foreignField: '_id',
                        as: 'upvotedUsers'
                    }
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        hasUpvoted: {
                            $in: [ObjectId(userId), '$upvote.user']
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 1,
                        content: 1,
                        timestamp: 1,
                        upvote: 1,
                        downvote: 1,
                        reply: 1,
                        author: {
                            $arrayElemAt: ['$author', 0]
                        },
                        hasUpvoted: 1
                    }
                }
            ]).toArray()
                .then((posts) => {
                    resolve(posts);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    }
```

I need fixes or explaination why this error. please help me...

Comment: Without sample input data, it is difficult to know your intention and provide any help. Maybe you need rather `$eq` than `$in`